# How to use an async function in another function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to call an async function making an API call inside another function.

Specifically in the code below I am defining an asynchronous function `verifyEmail` making an API call to a verification service for mail adresses. The function is working when I test it with a random email.

I would like to be able to call this function inside the `getProfileInfos` function that parses a json file and return an array of objects. The `verifyEmail(result.dropcontact.email)`is wrong since it will always return the non-resolved `Promise`. I did some research but do not find the right syntax to call the async function and wait for the result to set the email in my object.

Any help is appreciated!

```
const verifyEmail = async (email) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://apilayer.net/api/check?access_key=******&email=${email}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  if (data.format_valid && data.score > 0.5) {
    return data.email;
  };
}

const getProfileInfos = (data) => {
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  const results = jsonData.map((result) => {
    if (result.general) {
      const firstName = result.general.firstName;
      const lastName = result.general.lastName;
      const company = result.jobs[0].companyName;
      const jobTitle = result.jobs[0].jobTitle;
      const email = result.dropcontact ? verifyEmail(result.dropcontact.email) : undefined;
      return {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        company,
        jobTitle,
        email
      }
    }
  });
  return results;
}
```

Comment: you will also have to await the verifyEmail function, which also makes your getProfileInfos function an async function

Comment: Waiting for the result of a promise is done with the `await` keyword or `.then()` method. There is no wait to wait synchronously (blocking).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've tried to write it different (comments on next answer) but still not able to get the result of the promise inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Add `async` keyword to `getProfileInfos` and change line `const email = ...` to

```
const email = result.dropcontact ? (await verifyEmail(result.dropcontact.email)) : undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define async inside the `getProfileInfos` props and invoke await before verifyEmail

e.g.

```
const getProfileInfos = async (data) => {
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  const results = jsonData.map((result) => {
    if (result.general) {
      const firstName = result.general.firstName;
      const lastName = result.general.lastName;
      const company = result.jobs[0].companyName;
      const jobTitle = result.jobs[0].jobTitle;
      const email = result.dropcontact ? await verifyEmail(result.dropcontact.email) : undefined;
      return {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        company,
        jobTitle,
        email
      }
    }
  });
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm getting a syntax error, I guess it is because in this case `const results = jsonData.map((result)...` should be the async function. But when I try `jsonData.map(async (result)...` I just get an array of `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: try to console.log the jsonData and check if the array is fetching.

Comment: Probably you need to use .then() to get these data, if the Promise is pending something javascript is waiting for then().

Comment: Yes it is, the code works as expected when I don't use the `verifyEmail` function.
`const email = result.dropcontact ? result.dropcontact.email : undefined;` allows me to get the object I want.

Comment: `const email = result.dropcontact ? await verifyEmail(result.dropcontact.email).then(email => email) : undefined;` I tried this as well but still not returning the verified email